# Regularity result for the elliptic equation with Neumann conditions

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

I am having troubles to justify well some inequalities related with the classical
theory of elliptic equations. Let us consider the problem
\begin{align*}
-\Delta c  & =f,\text{  in }\Omega\\
\frac{\partial c}{\partial n}  & =0,\text{ on }\partial\Omega.
\end{align*}
on a bounded smooth domain $\Omega,$ satisfying 
\begin{align*}
\int_\Omega cdx & =\int_{\Omega}f=0.
\end{align*}
My question is, if the inequality 
\begin{align*}
\left\Vert c\right\Vert _{W^{2,p}(\Omega)}\leq C\left\Vert f\right\Vert
_{L^{p}(\Omega)}
\end{align*}
holds for all $p>1$ and what happens when $p=1,$ e.g. Can I say something
about.$\left\Vert \nabla c\right\Vert _{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}$ in the two
dimensional case? I would highly appreciate some precise reference.

**Extra:** In Grisvard's book there is a similar related result (Th. 2.4.1.3) that
applies for
\begin{align*}
-\Delta c+ac  & =f,\text{  in }\Omega\\
\frac{\partial c}{\partial n}  & =0,\text{  on }\partial\Omega.
\end{align*}
as far as $"a"$ is larger than some positive constant $\lambda_{\Omega}$ and
the conclusion is
\begin{align*}
\left\Vert c\right\Vert _{W^{2,p}(\Omega)}\leq C\left(  \left\Vert
c\right\Vert _{L^{p}(\Omega)}+\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{L^{p}(\Omega)}\right)
\text{  for }p>1\text{.}%
\end{align*}
Therefore my question is also "What happens if $a>0$ is an arbitrary positive constant?"